# Customizing xml output with IXmlSerializable

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-serialization

What I am trying to achieve seems fairly simple.

Given the class

```
public class Wrapper<T> { 
   T Data { get; set; }
   bool Success { get;set; }
   List<Error> Errors { get; set; }
}
```

I simply want to have the XML output for the Data parameter wrapped in a `<Data></Data>` tag.

IE: 
Desired output:

```
<Wrapper>
    <Data>
       <Person first="Bob" last="Robertson"/>
    </Data>
   <Errors/>
    <Success>true</Success>
</Wrapper
```

Actual output:

```
<Wrapper>
    <Person first="Bob" last="Robertson"/>
    <Errors/>
    <Success>true</Success>
</Wrapper>
```

Is there a simple implementation of IXmlSerializable where I can leave the serialization alone for the most part and just wrap the one member?

Edit: This is in a WCF service so I don't (as far as I know) have access to the creation of the XmlSerializer.

**What I ended up doing:**

```
    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteElementString("Success", Success.ToString());
        writer.WriteStartElement("Errors");

        foreach (var error in Errors)
        {
            Util.XmlSerialize(error, writer);
        }

        writer.WriteStartElement("Data");
        Util.XmlSerialize(this.Data, writer);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
```

-

```
public class Util
{
    public static void XmlSerialize<T>(T obj, XmlWriter writer)
    {
        var nsSerializer = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        nsSerializer.Add("", "");

        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof (T));
        ser.Serialize(writer, obj, nsSerializer);
    }
}
```

Comment: @onof: I have tried numorous things but felt like I was going down the road of re-implementing XmlSerializer (eg, honoring annotations etc).  Figured there may be an easy way that I had overlooked.  I also tried restructuring my code to better match my desired format but that seemed really smelly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XmlOverrides:

```
var xmlOverrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
var attributes = new XmlAttributes();
attributes.XmlElements
     .Add(new XmlElementAttribute("Person", typeof (Person)));
xmlOverrides.Add(typeof(Wrapper<Person>), "Data", attributes);

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Wrapper<ExampleObject>), xmlOverrides);
```

Comment: Here's the curveball: this is in WCF and I'm specifying [XmlSerializerFormat] on the service contract so I'm not in charge of creating the XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

**Schema**

```
public class Wrapper<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}


public class Person
{
    public string first;
    public string last;
}
```

**XML Serialization**

```
        Wrapper<Person> f = new Wrapper<Person>();
        f.Data = new Person();
        f.Data.first = "Bob";
        f.Data.last = "Robertson";
        XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Wrapper<Person>));
        TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter(@"C:\test.xml");
        SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, f);
        WriteFileStream.Close();
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WrapperOfPerson xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Data>
    <first>Bob</first>
    <last>Robertson</last>
  </Data>
  <Success>false</Success>
</WrapperOfPerson>
```

Comment: That is what I have currently.  What I'm looking for would be `<Data><Person><first>Bob</first><last>Robertson</last></Person></Data>`

Comment: You can only get either Data tag or person tag.